Django async aadd() not working on ManyRelatedManager models?
Recently I have been developing an app using Django ninja.
I want to add Group to user groups, and statement seems have no effect. It does not commit to db. I tried atomic, and all solutions but it does not work. I have db for tests:
    settings.DATABASES["default"] = {
    "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
    "NAME": ":memory:",
    "ATOMIC_REQUESTS": False,
    "TIME_ZONE": "America/Chicago",
    "CONN_HEALTH_CHECKS": True,
    "CONN_MAX_AGE": 0,
    "OPTIONS": {},
    "AUTOCOMMIT": True
}

This is code:
    group = await cls.repository.get_group_by_name(name)
    assert group

    await user.groups.aadd(group)

In Django documentation this should work just fine, but it does not. I use AsyncClient from Django to run tests.
Any advice ?

So how do you know/check it does not add it?

I checked every single query and commit to db. No found. Also test does not show any groups after receiving user.groups.aall()

I noticed, when I use PostgreSQL It works as expected, so it seems the error is only with test db. Any advice?

Ok, it seems I did not remember that Django does not allow to m2m relations during object creation. Simple solution:
    @receiver(post_save, sender=CustomUser, dispatch_uid="custom_user_saved")
async def custom_user_post_save(sender, instance, created, signal, update_fields, **kwargs):

    if created:
        await UserService.configure_new_user(instance)

